# Trying to have a way for a user to select language

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, internationalization

I am working on an Angular application for a school project and the teacher wants us to have a way for the user to have access to different translated versions of our app. I have no idea how to approach this. I have two xlf files for translation and am able to use these along with my ng serve configurations to build my app in French, English and Latin and I have radio buttons to pick which language you want. However, when it comes down to having a live translation of my app when a different radio button is selected, I have nothing. I am just looking for suggestions. Thank you in advance

Comment: [This](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview) should be a good start.  If you get stuck, be sure to ask as a new, **specific** question.